# Can not play audio in didReceiveData method of Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, avcapturesession, multipeer-connectivity

My aim is to stream voice data to multiple devices using multipeer connnectivity.

I am using AVCaptureSession to access voice data from microphone using AVCaptureDevice type AVMediaTypeAudio.

In a custom AVCaptureAudioDataOutput class i am getting those audio data and want to stream that to all connected peers.

```
//sending data using Multipeer Connectivity

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    //  NSLog(@"---A U D I O :%@",sampleBuffer);

    AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
    NSMutableData *data= [NSMutableData data];
    CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);

    for( int y=0; y< audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++ ){
        AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
        Float32 *frame = (Float32*)audioBuffer.mData;

        [data appendBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];
    }

    CFRelease(blockBuffer);
    [_session sendData:data toPeers:_session.connectedPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:nil];
}
```

In the Receiver application I am getting all nsdata in didRecievedData delegate method in MCSessionDelegate.

But I am not getting any way to play that raw NSData in Reciever application.

Comment: hey @Abhijit try to implement the play functionality in DidFinishloading method

Comment: But how can I can convert the raw NSData to playable audio data

Comment: try to AVAudioPlayer

Comment: I have already tried this.But its not working.
AVAudioPlayer *player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
    [player setVolume:1.0];
    [player setNumberOfLoops:1];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];

Comment: You might find this useful, though I haven't independently verified it. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity -- BTW, you say "stream" but you send "data" -- these terms mean different things (I'm not just being pedantic). If you mean stream, you might want to look at the stream-specific send/receive methods (startStreamWithName/didReceiveStream)